# Чтение координат из текстового файла

Tags: c, координаты

Помогите пожалуйста, никак не могу додуматься как добавить в код чтение координат из текстового файла.
Вот мой изначальный код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int x1, y1;
int x2, y2;
int x3, y3;
int x4, y4;
printf("First quadrilateral\n");
printf("Coordinates for A: ");
scanf("%d%d",&x1,&y1);
printf("Coordinates for B: ");
scanf("%d%d",&x2,&y2);
printf("Coordinates for C: ");
scanf("%d%d",&x3,&y3);
printf("Coordinates for D: ");
scanf("%d%d",&x4,&y4);

int x5, y5;
int x6, y6;
int x7, y7;
int x8, y8;
printf("Second quadrilateral\n");
printf("Coordinates for E: ");
scanf("%d%d",&x5,&y5);
printf("Coordinates for F: ");
scanf("%d%d",&x6,&y6);
printf("Coordinates for G: ");
scanf("%d%d",&x7,&y7);
printf("Coordinates for H: ");
scanf("%d%d",&x8,&y8);

if ( (x1 < x5 && y1 < y5) && (x2 < x6 && y2 > y6) && (x3 > x7 && y3 > y7) && (x4 > x8 && y4 < y8) )
    printf("Inside");
else
    printf("Not inside");
return 0;
```

}

txt файл с координатами выглядит так:

```
3 2 3 10
15 10 15 2
5 4 5 8
12 8 12 4
```

Comment: Файл с координатами привести забыли...

Comment: Ну, наверное, заменить `scanf` на `fscanf` для чтения из файла... Или перенаправить файл на стандартный ввод в командной строке.